# What do different supercharges corrrespond to? Is creation mathematically close to fock space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, hilbert-space, supersymmetry

We may have $I =1,2,..N$ where it is said that this corresponds to $N$ supercharges, $Q^I$.
By the supersymmetry algebra, $$[M_{\mu\nu},{\overline{Q}}^{I\dot{\alpha}}] = i(\sigma_{\mu\nu}){^{\dot{\alpha}}_{\dot{\beta}}}{\overline{Q}}^{I\dot{\beta}}$$
By this relation, we find $Q$ to be lowering and raising of $J_z$ by $\frac{1}{2}$.

From the other part of the super symmetry algebra $$\{Q_\alpha,{\overline{Q}}_{\dot{\beta}}\} = 2\sigma^{\mu}_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}P_{\mu}$$
For a massive irrep, we see that it forms the Clifford algebra of the form $\{a_\alpha,a^\dagger_\alpha\} =2M$. All of this is taken for granted. Now, my question is, when there is more than 1 supercharge which follows the exact same procedure as above. Then how are the states $a^{1\dagger}_\alpha|\Omega\rangle$ and $a^{2\dagger}_\alpha|\Omega\rangle$ any different? Here, $\Omega$ is the clifford vaccum and $a^{1\dagger}_\alpha$ is the creating operator from $Q^1$ and $a^{2\dagger}_\alpha$ is the creating operator from the second supercharge $Q^2$ Don't both the operators just raise the spin by $\frac{1}{2}$. What is the need for 2 such operators. Do they act on 2 different $J_z$ or something? I'm completely lost at this point. Some clarification would be helpful!

My second question is, In the context of QFT. A particle is created by acting the creation operator $|1\rangle = a^\dagger_p|0\rangle$. When I act another operator on this, I get $|2\rangle = a^\dagger_p a^\dagger_p|0\rangle$ which is in some sense a tensor product of 2 states with momenta $p,q$ right? (I'm not completely sure of the notation, what is it actually?)

Similarly, what does $a^{2\dagger}_\alpha a^{1\dagger}_\alpha|\Omega\rangle$ correspond to in mathematical language? Do they act as operators on 2 separate tensor products or does the spin just end up increasing by 1? Just to have an idea of things.

**EDIT:** So, I've noticed one thing. When I have $N$ supercharges. I've a way of creating a $\pm \frac{N}{2}$ state. Whereas, with just 1, it wouldnt be possible. As, the action of $a^{1\dagger}$ on the same state twice gives me 0. I feel this is a cheap answer. There must be a more general requirement of $N$ supercharges. As an analogy, we have $4$ bosonoic $P_\mu$ charges which correspond to translation in 4-d space-time. Now, $N$ $Q$'s correspond to translation of $N$ Grassmann valued coordinates on super-space. In that setting perhaps?